# How to use python to print files to pdf in Chrome

Tags: python, pdf-generation

I have a large amount of files I want to open in Chrome, and then use Chrome's print to save as pdf option on. Does anyone know what would be the best way to do this in Python -- is there any python package to use that would make this easy?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to save it from Python to a directory with your chosen   file type without the need of opening it in Chrome?

Comment: This seems rather roundabout. Are you just trying to download many PDFs from an online source?

Comment: The reason I am doing this is to unsecure PDFs. Printing to PDFs in Chrome does this.